# Renaming zip to match it's contents using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, 7zip, file-rename

As part of automating the backup of some of our development logfiles I am using Powershell script and would like to rename a 7zip file I just created to match the last part of the name of the first file and the last part of the last file in the archive.

For example; I have three files, file1-03082013.log, file2-04082013.log and file3-05082013.log, these are compressed using an automated Powershell and 7zip script for creating log.zip. Now I want to rename log.zip to log-03082013 - 05082013 (matching the last part of the first file and the last part of the last file in the archive I've just created).

Here is the complete script I've created thusfar. (I am quite a newby to scripting in Powershell, so any comments on how to improve my existing script are highly welcome as well) Hope you guys can help out in any way! Thanks in advance!

```
#Variables

$Source = "C:\Path\"
$Destination = "C:\ZIP"
$Temp = "C:\Templog\"
$Previous = "C:\Templog\"
$programma = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

#Copy files to TempFolder

Function CopyFile
{
Copy-Item -Recurse -Filter "*.svclog" -path $Source -Destination $Temp
}
CopyFile

#Delete Old Log Files on server

Function DelOldFile
{
if (Test-Path $Source)
{
$Days = "7" 
$Now = Get-Date
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$days)
$Files = get-childitem $Source -include *.svclog -recurse |Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}
foreach ($File in $Files)
{write-host "Deleting file $File" -foregroundcolor "Red"; Remove-Item $File | out-null}
}
Else
{Write-Host "The folder $Source doesn't exist! Check the folder path!" -foregroundcolor "red"}
}
DelOldFile

#Create .zip archive from files and folders in Temp folder and copy to destination folder using 7zip.

Function ZipFile
{
Start-Process $programma -ArgumentList "a $Destination\Log.zip $Temp" -Wait -PassThru
}
ZipFile

#Delete Temp Folder

Function GetPrevious
{
if (Test-Path $Previous){
    Remove-Item $Previous -Recurse -Force
    }
}
GetPrevious
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you here's a function to get the name of the zip file based on your requirements, just pass it the location of your log files:

```
function Get-ZipFileName
{
    param
    ($logPath)

    # Get a list of files, remove the extension and split on the hyphen, #
    # then take the second part of the array 
    $filenames = gci -Path $logPath -Filter "*.log" | % { $($_.Basename -split "-")[1] }

    # Get the first item in the now sorted list
    $first = $filenames | Sort-Object | Select-Object -First 1

    # Get the first item in the sorted list, now descending to get the last
    $last  = $filenames | Sort-Object -descending | Select-Object -First 1

    # return the filename
    "log-{0} - {1}" -f $first, $last
}
```

I would suggest you look at using a slightly different date format that will sort better, yyyymmdd will sort better than ddmmyyyy.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much. I've edited and tweaked the script to suit our needs better. Thanks a bunch! Is there a way to share my completed script so that it is available for all to use?

Comment: Glad to help, you could add your completed script as an answer if you think it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Using Davids help I eventually came up with the following completed script.
Hopefully it will help you guys in future challenges as well.

Please let me know if you have any comments or questions about this finished script.

```
#=============================================
#
#   Recursive Log Search, Archive & Del Script
#   Ver. 1.0.0  06/08/2013
#   Roelof Wijnholds
#
#=============================================

#Enter parentfolder
$sPath = "Path\to\parent\folder"

#Folder where the archive will be created (if it doesn't exist, folder will be created)
$tPath = "archive"

#Path to 7zip executable
$7z = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"


checkForWebservices $sPath 5

#Check for bin & log folder & *.extension file
function checkValidWebservice($path)
{
    If((Test-Path $path\bin) -and (Test-Path $path\log) -and (Test-Path $path\*.svc)){
        write-host "Valid webservice structure found: " $path 
        return $true
    }else{
        return $false
    }
}

function checkForWebservices($path, $max, $level = 0)
{
    $path = (Resolve-Path $path).ProviderPath
    foreach ($item in @(Get-ChildItem $path))
    {
        if ($item.Attributes -eq "Directory")
        {
            if(checkValidWebservice $path)
            {
                #Create name for compressed file
                $fileName = CreateCompressFileName $path
                if($fileName -ne $null)
                {
                    #Compress files in folder
                    CompressAndRemoveLogFiles $fileName $path
                    Write-Host "Compressing and removing files"
                }
                return
            }else{
                checkForWebservices $item.PSPath $max ($level + 1) 
            }

            #Break if recursive goes to DEEP
            if ($level -eq $max)
            {
                Write-Host "Max depth" $path\$item - $level
                return 
            }
        }
    }
}

function CreateCompressFileName($path)
{
    #Get startingdate from file
    $fileNameFrom = Get-ChildItem $path\log | Where {$_.Extension -eq ".svclog"} | Sort-Object name | Select-Object -first 1
    if($fileNameFrom -ne $null)
    {
        #Get first file
        if($fileBaseName -eq $null)
        {
            #File is supposed to be servicename_20130508.svclog
            $fileBaseName = $fileNameFrom.BaseName.SubString(0,$fileNameFrom.BaseName.length - 9)
        }
        $fileNameFrom = $fileNameFrom.BaseName.SubString($fileNameFrom.BaseName.length - 8,8)
        #Get last file
        $fileNameTo = Get-ChildItem $path\log | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt ((Get-Date).Date) -and $_.Extension -eq ".svclog" } | Sort-Object name -descending | Select-Object -first 1  

        if($fileNameTo -ne $null)
        {
            $fileNameTo = $fileNameTo.BaseName.SubString($fileNameTo.BaseName.length - 8,8)
            #Compile the name
            return $fileBaseName+"_"+$fileNameFrom+"_"+$fileNameTo
        }
    }
    return $null    
}

function CompressAndRemoveLogFiles($fileName, $path)
{
    $cFiles = Get-ChildItem $path\log | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt ((Get-Date).Date) -and $_.Extension -eq ".svclog" } 

    Foreach ($item in $cFiles)
    {
        #Add file to archive
        $endPath = $path.TrimStart($sPath)
        $target = "{0}\{1}\{2}\{3}" -f $sPath,$tPath,$endPath,$fileName

        $result = & $7z a -mx5 -mmt $target $item.FullName
        #Cleanup files
        Remove-Item $path\log\$item
    }
}
```